# Javascript List Box Population Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

It needs to work in IE, if that matters. This is supposed to populate a table cell based on a selection from a listbox. Later on, I'll change the photo to be some HTML that adds their picture to the box.

HTML:

```
<script src="garver_contact.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <select class="col1 selectTopic">
                <option>Payroll</option>
                <option>Tax</option>
                <option>Accounts Payable</option>
            </select>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1 name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1 photo"></td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col1 email"></td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col1 phone"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script src="contact.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
data = {
    "contacts":
{
    "contact": [
{
    "name": "Payroll",
    "photo": "Emp 1 Photo",
    "email": "emp1@gusa.com",
    "phone": "4113834848"
},
{
    "name": "Tax",
    "photo": "Emp 2 Photo",
    "email": "emp2@usa.com",
    "phone": "4113834848"
},
{
    "name": "Accounts Payable",
    "photo": "Emp 3 Photo",
    "email": "emp3@usa.com",
    "phone": "4113834848"
},
    ]
}
}

$(".selectTopic").change(function () {
    var jthis = $(this);
    var whichCol;
    if (jthis.hasClass("col1")) {
        whichCol = "col1";
    }
    $.each(data.contacts.contact, function (i, v) {
        if (v.name == jthis.val()) {
            $("td." + whichCol + ".name").html(v.name);
            $("td." + whichCol + ".photo").html(v.photo);
            $("td." + whichCol + ".email").html(v.email);
            $("td." + whichCol + ".phone").html(v.phone);
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this working in any browser? Is the data coming from an external source?  If not, you need to bind the data to a variable.

Comment: Is it not working in any browser. Nor is the data coming from an external source. Can you explain "bind the data to a variable?"  Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you're declaring the data object locally, make sure data is a variable and there's a semicolon at the end. Else, if it is an external data source, try `.parseJSON(data.contacts.contact)` in your `.each` function.

Comment: Do you mean like this:                                                                                      var data = {
        "contacts":
    {
        "contact": [
    {
        "name": "Payroll",
        "photo": "Emp 1 Photo",
        "email": "emp1@usa.com",
        "phone": "4113834848"
    },
    {
        "name": "Tax",
        "photo": "Emp 2 Photo",
        "email": "emp2@usa.com",
        "phone": "4113834848"
    },
    {
        "name": "Accounts Payable",
        "photo": "Emp 3 Photo",
        "email": "emp3@usa.com",
        "phone": "4113834848"
    },
        ]
    }
    };

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0po0c2h8/ Nope, no luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: For JSFiddle to work, you need to select the jQuery framework (if you aren't doing this for your project outside the fiddle you need to); otherwise, your `$` is undefined, and get rid of the `script` tags in your HTML, and select `load type` of `No wrap  - in <body>` from the JavaScript options. To use in production code, you should wrap your JavaScript in a `$(document).ready(` function call. See https://jsfiddle.net/0po0c2h8/2/